# Hiding elements in Android WebView with Javascript

Tags: javascript, android, webview

I'm trying to hide following part:

```
<table border="0" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"class="header">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td align="center"><img src="images/logo.png" border="0" style="height:29px;"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>   
</table>
```

My code:

```
public class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String Url) {
        view.loadUrl("javascript:document.getElementByClassName('header').style.display = 'none';");
    }
}
```

If it helps answering my question the site I'm talking about is http://vs-go.de/ (The mobile version).

Edit: I forgot the 'actual' code part, sorry.

```
    myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    myWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    myWebViewClient = new MyWebViewClient();
    myWebView.setWebViewClient(myWebViewClient);
    myWebView.loadUrl("http://vs-go.de/");
```

myWebView is globally defined on the top of the code.

Answer (score 1):

Can't test out right now if this is the only error here, but it is

`getElementsByClassName`

You are missing the **s** in the middle.

---

Second error:

`getElementsByClassName` returns an array.

So `javascript:document.getElementsByClassName('header')[0].style.display = 'none';`
should be working for you. Just tested it in a normaler Browser behaving as mobile device, no problem.

Comment: That was definitly one of the errors but it still shows the header in the Webview (which I'm trying to hide).

Comment: Updated my answer, this should be want you wanted to achieve

Comment: Sort of worked. It hides but it hides everything and shows "none" as text. If I insert the code in a chrome console it works. Weird.

Comment: Update: Every now and then the app blinks. -> http://puu.sh/lghpA/50f3f85f8e.mp4 Why does this happen?

Comment: http://www.pic-upload.de/view-28816800/result.png.html this is how it looks like in a Chrome with mobile view. Can you please show me the line that you changed? The blinking is weird, but I guess this has to do with the JavaScript being executed wrong.

Comment: I just changed view.loadUrl("javascript:document.getElementsByClassName('header')[0].style.display = 'none';

Comment: `");` is not missing at the end?

Comment: I'm installing Android Studio at my work now, so I can reproduce your error and helpy you solve it

Comment: yeah it's not there in the comment, copy paste fail. sorry. and that really nice of you! :)

Comment: By the way, are you running on an emulator or on a real Android device?

Comment: On a real device. (Oneplus One)

Comment: Oh and also If you need the project I can provide the source if you want to.

Comment: Source code would be great. Sadly Android Studio won't work at my work, so I will have a look at it this evening at home and get back to you then.

Comment: Hey, sry I didn't make it yesterday. I will try to do this this evening, when I have a little bit more time. I **will** do it eventually